# Is the "Force" of Gravity Simply Hamilton's Principle on a Curved Spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, potential, variational-principle

It's my understanding that [General Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) abstracts away the concept of gravity as a force, and instead describes it as a feature of spacetime by which massive objects cause curvature.  Then it follows that what we experience as a force is simply the difference between a geodesic on this curved surface and our perceived Euclidean space.  What I am unsure of, exactly, is the implication of this.

$$S[q] \equiv \int L(q(t), \tfrac{ \delta q }{ \delta t }(t), t)dt$$
and [Hamilton's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) states that 
$$\tfrac{\delta S}{\delta q(t)} = 0.$$

If 
$$F(q(t)) = -\nabla U(q(t)) = \nabla (T(\tfrac{ \delta q }{ \delta t}(t)) - U(q(t))) = \nabla L,$$
which, as I understand is true for a conservative field like gravitation, then are these two statements not equivalent?

What additional insight do we gain by using principles of differential geometry versus classical potential theory?